# Is there a python spelling correction library that corrects capitalisation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, spell-checking, capitalization, autocapitalize

I have strings that are spelled correctly but in all lower case (except for the first character), that I would like to correct for capitalisation (in English - so basically just names of things...). I tried pyspellcheck, autocorrect and symspellpy, which do not consider capitalisation afaik.

So for example the string `'And then we went to see frank from england to have a beer with him.'` should be corrected to `'And then we went to see Frank from England to have a beer with him.'`.

Do you know any library that can do that?

Comment: Please add details to your question, as it stands, is bound to be close. A good set examples is going to help to

Comment: I have added an example is it more clear now?

Comment: You can do like this only a = "today is my day"
print(a.title())

Comment: @EhsanRahi no that's not it, I want a spell check for capitalisation. Please look at the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with spaCy:

```
import spacy
nlp=spacy.load('en_core_web_md')


def capitalize_ent(text):
    title_text=text.title()
    print(text)
    doc=nlp(title_text)
    words=[]
    for x in doc:
        if nlp(x.text).ents:
            words.append(x.text)
    for word in words:
        text=text.replace(word.lower(),word)
    return text
```

Don't forget to download the spaCy language model:

```
python -m spacy download en_core_web_md
```